# Boolean in action array (swift)

Tags: arrays, xcode, swift, boolean

I have an action array, and when this array is completed, I want to change value Move to false.

this is my array:

```
 actionArray.addObject(SKAction.moveToY(hond.position.y + 0.4 * frame2.size.height, duration: timee/10))
    actionArray.addObject(SKAction.moveToY(hond.position.y + 0.6 * frame2.size.height, duration: timee/12))
    actionArray.addObject(SKAction.moveToY(hond.position.y + 0.7 * frame2.size.height, duration: timee/14))
    actionArray.addObject(SKAction.moveToY(hond.position.y + 0.75 * frame2.size.height, duration: timee/16))
    hond.runAction(SKAction.sequence(actionArray))
```

How do I add a object that will change the boolean add the end of the array?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> SKAction Class Reference : http://goo.gl/zqqh5k

You can use a `runBlock:` action, from `SKAction` and add it at the end of your sequence.

For example :

```
SKAction.runBlock(self.aFunction)

func aFunction() {
    // Change your boolean value here
}
```

Or :

```
SKAction.runBlock({ self.yourBooleanProperty = false })
```